# uploadify fails to upload files

Tags: php, directory, uploadify

I made a small script which basically uses jQuery uplodify to upload files to dynamically generated directories. It works fine on my localhost but does nothing on my remote test server.
I inspected the traffic with fiddler and noticed the following warnings are issued:

**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(/data/web/uploaded_videos/majid/file.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/data/web/14/2d/81/jqeedu.tuxfamily.org/htdocs/file_upload/res/uploadify.php** on line **40**

**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/data/web/tmp/phpRHJQQx' to '/data/web/uploaded_videos/majid/file.txt' in **/data/web/14/2d/81/jqeedu.tuxfamily.org/htdocs/file_upload/res/uploadify.php** on line **40**

When I inspect the directory structure of the remote server I see that the `tmp` directory is actually outside `htdocs` and both are in the same directory. Is this what is causing the failure? How should I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are:

- Specifying the correct path
- Directories have permission, chmod to 755
- You have put `enctype` in `form` attribute
- Data is coming through, check with:

  `print_r($_FILES);`